# Cancel exception propogation

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

When this request results in an error the then method after the catch method runs. How do I stop it running code when there's an error?

```
return fetch('url here', {

            credentials: "same-origin"
        })
            .then(res => {

                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(err => {

                console.log(err)
            })
            .then(d => console.log('What am I doing here?'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `return` statement in your catch

```
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return;
})
```

Comment: Aha.. fantastic.

Comment: The return statement exits a function from anywhere within the function: